# Where in Spree is the prices table joined to the products for lists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I modified Spree so that a product/variant can have more than one price. This means a product has a `one_time` price, a `recurring_price` and a `consumption_price`. For this I added a `price_type` field to the Price model. Now I have a problem with lists. The product gets listed three times because somewhere the prices are inner joined resulting in 3 entries in the list for the three different price types. Where do I fix this, meaning inner joining only `price_type = one_time` for lists (or in general until otherwise specified)?

Comment: Can you provide the model associations to make your question more clear? An example of how to clearly display model associations can be found in: Active Record Associations - 2.4 The `has_many :through` Association. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out and it works for me so far:

```rb
Spree::Product.class_eval do

  class << self
    alias_method :orig_available, :available

    def available(available_on = nil, _currency = nil)
      orig_available(available_on, _currency).where("#{Spree::Price.quoted_table_name}.price_type = ?", Spree::Price.price_types[:one_time])
    end

  end
end
```